# Getting different hash(sha 256) using solidity and python for same bytes

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, solidity, sha256

Solidity code

```
string memory str= string(abi.encodePacked(orderId, msg.sender, totalAmount));
        bytes memory encodedString = abi.encodePacked(str);
        bytes32 calculatedHash = sha256(encodedString);
        emit LogData(calculatedHash,encodedString);
```

I took encodedString and used it in Python code:

Python Code:

```
import hashlib

my_string = encodedString

my_bytes = bytes(my_string, 'utf-8')

print(hashlib.sha256(my_bytes).hexdigest())
```

but I am getting two different hashes from these two codes. Can someone tell me the error and correction.

I want these two hashes to be alike

Comment: Hint: compare the string after encoding but before hashing

Comment: str is holding some unreadable string because of uint and address type of value, so i changed them to string first and then I got readable value in str. so now if i use the same value of str as my_string instead of encodedString i get same hash.